# Map JSON object to different schema field names

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a schema which is supposed to save data which comes from a third party API. Unfortunately the given names by that API are kinda poor and I would like to use proper names for my schema / database.

**API response example:**
I shortned the response a lot. It has around 20 fields.

```
let apiResponse = {
    id: {high:1, low:388},
    username:"xyz",
    addr: [{
        fdn: "Street 123",
        dq: "5534"
    },{
        fdn: "Street 456",
        dq: "1102"
    }]
}
```

My Schema looks like this:

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    account_id: {
        high: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        low: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    addresses: [{
        street: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        zip: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }],
})
```

**My question:**

1. What would be the best way to map these dumb original names to my schema field names?
2. Should I simply create a helper function or is there a mongoose feature I could use for this "mapping process"?
3. I often see APIs which use camelCase named fields, but mongodb prefers snake_case. Should I ignore the mongodb naming conventions so that I don't need such a "mapping"?

Comment: Sounds like you will have to create a map either way.  Now it's a matter to do it.  1 & 2, You can perform it at the mongoose middleware level, by hooking into  userSchema.pre('validate', function(){}).  Map to the correct fields here before it goes up the tree into save.  Make sure to delete fields you don't want showing in ur db.   3, is a matter of preference.  if it's your code, your build, i don't see why you cannot use the preferred naming scheme.

Comment: Another approach you can try is implementing a mapper in the schema's static function.  Run every new field through this function and return the correct document.  userSchema.statics.map = function(apiObject){//map stuff, return mapped object}.  This way the incoming apiResponse data and mapping function stays within the realm of your userSchema.

Comment: @Nuspeed1 I assume I want to use pre('validate') so that my validators like required will check that. If you could give a quick code example you could probably wrap this up as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Edit: After trying pre('validate') I noticed this wouldn't work for upsert because findOneAndUpdate has a different behaviour for the hooks. So I will probably go with the static function on the Schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you think about this approach but you can also append values to the schema field that may later be referenced through the options object.

For example, I added **alias** as a property to street and zip.

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    addresses: [{
        street: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            **alias**: "fdn"
        },
        zip: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            **alias**: "dq"
        }
    }],
})
```

Which can then be referenced through mongoose.  Check the fields surrounded by asterisks in your debug console for it's structure.

```
mongoose.models.**UserSchema**.schema.paths.**addresses.street**.options.alias
```

Then you can use it in a loop to find the schema property's other name.

Comment: That sounds interessting as well, are there any downsides?

Comment: it's attached to your schema object like any other key/value pair, but just to be safe, I would make sure to give it a unique name that will future proof mongoose updates to the options object.  the benefit is that you may reference it from any part of your code just by require('mongoose').  so if you decide to consolidate all your mappings code across all schemas into one module, you have access to it via this approach.