# how to match headers of CSV file with collection fields in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mapping

When i upload a CSV file, in CSV file all the header i have are capital and with space when i upload i am getting below json. I want to match the join object with table fields of my schema

```
{
  'Partner Name': '',
  'Mobile No 1': '',
  'Mobile No 2': '',
  'Vendor / DCO / Aggregator / Labour': '',
  'Source of lead': '',
  'Vehicle type': '',
  'Count of vehicle available': '',
  'Vehicle number (separated by comma)': '',
  'Vehicle body type': '',
  'Partner Base Region': '',
  'Partner base subregion': '',
 }
```

This image is my schema in schema i created all fields with underscore and small case letter

[image]

Comment: Well, the easiest approach for you would be to use the [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to map the db fields to the required once(*although you could rename the fields with an underscore while uploading if no business need is there*). As an alternative, you could make use of [aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393320/2417602) in mongoose

Comment: Just transform `Partner Name` to `partner_name`, `Partner Base Region` to `base_region`... It's just a little text manipulation

Comment: i am using aliasing in mongoose but how to access the object which is aliasing is done, not able understand how to access the i did like this but its throwing errors  alternate_no: records[i].alternate_no.options.alias, i did like this @vikscool

Comment: @Deepak have a look at [Example of using alias](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6427#issuecomment-387395578)